# An element in a ring reduced modulo a prime ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I am reading scheme theory and this thing in the prime spectrum perplexed me. An element in a ring $A$ reduced modulo a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ is an element in the residue field of $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$. For example, $A = \mathbb{Z}$. Then $25\ mod\ (17)$ is $\overline{8}$ in field $\mathbb{F}_{17}$. How do we prove that the reduced element is in the residue field rather than just an element in $A/(\mathfrak{p})$?

Comment: $A_{\mathfrak p}$ is not normally used to indicate the residue field, but the localization of $A$ at $\mathfrak p,$ which is a ring.

Comment: Also, $A/\mathfrak p$ is not always a field. And we don't need parentheses around $\mathfrak p$ in that notation.

Comment: An element $a\in A$ can be localized to get the element $a/1\in A_{\mathfrak p}$, and this element can be reduced modulo the maximal ideal $\mathfrak pA_{\mathfrak p}\subset A_{\mathfrak p}$, giving an element of the residue field.

Comment: Also, the map $A\to A_{\mathfrak p},a\mapsto a/1$ induces a map $A/\mathfrak p\to A_\mathfrak p/\mathfrak pA_{\mathfrak p}$.

Comment: @danneks Thank you so much! It's clear now.